# how to populate the collection of child registers?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I have an application that uses EF 5.0. Suppose That I have two tables:

```
tableA(IDTableA, IDTableB...)
TableB(IDTableB, ...)
```

When I query for elements of the  tableA, I can do:

```
List<TableA> lstResult = myContext.TableA.SQLQuery("select * from TableA").ToList();
```

However, in  this case the collection TableA.TableA in an entity of type TableA is not populate, is null, so I need to do other query:

1.- Convert all the IDs of my entity in lstResult to string in format ID1, ID2... I name this string strIDs.

2.- I do the query:

```
lst<TableB) lstResult2 = myContext.tableB.SQLQuery("select * from TableB where IDTableB IN(" + strIDs + ")").ToList();
```

In this moment, EF populates the colletion IDTableB in the tableA.

So this makes me do two queries. One to get the register of TableA and other to get the registers of TableB and know the relation between them.

If tableA has many FKs, then I need many additional queries, so I think that this is inefficient.

Lazy loading eorks in a similar way, do this additional queries when I need the information. However, I don't want to use lazy loading, because my dataContext has a short live, so when I return the entities as result of the query, when I try to get the childs records I get an error that says that the entity out of the context.

So other solution is to use a view, but I would like to know if it is posible to populate the child.

Also, I would like to use raw sql, because for dynamic queries for me is easier to create the query.

Thanks.